# What does adding a second parameter in a for loop with nested enumerate() do?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, enumerate

I'm trying myself on Python again and I want to create a text-based Ticktacktoe.

Currently, I am working on the layout with 0 representing the empty spaces in the games and numbers up top and on the left for coordinates.This is what I have so far:

```
game = [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],]

print('   0  1  2')

for row in enumerate(game):
    print(row)
```

which outputs this :

```
     0  1  2
(0, [0, 0, 0])
(1, [0, 0, 0])
(2, [0, 0, 0])
```

The problem is that I want it to look like this:

```
   0  1  2
0 [0, 0, 0]
1 [0, 0, 0]
2 [0, 0, 0]
```

Now I found a way by adding 'count' into the for loop. But I don't understand why at all.
Looking up the Python documentation did not help.
Why is this happening? Why does that get rid of the brackets and commas?

```
game = [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],]

print('   0  1  2')

for count, row in enumerate(game):
    print(count, row)
```

Edit: I think I understand now.Since `enumarate()` returns the Index and the value all that's basically happening is that I assigned `count` to the Index and row to basically the value? And that is why there are now brackets since print prints more than 1 variable using a space? Could you confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example a tuple will be passed to `print()`, which is printed enclosed in parenthesis. In the second answer the row count and the row itself are passed as separate arguments to `print()` - `print()` will then print the arguments space separated.

Answer (score 3):

`for row in enumerate(game):`

This will print `row`, which is a tuple. Tuples are printed in the format
    (item1, item2, ...)

Example:

```
>>> row = (5, [0,0,0])
>>> print(row)
(5, [0,0,0])
```

`for count, row in enumerate(game):`
Here, the result is unpacked. What was a tuple is now split into `count` and `row`. `print` can take a variable number of arguments, and by default it separates them with a space.

Example:

```
>>> count = 5
>>> row = [0,0,0]
>>> print(count, row)
5 [0,0,0]
```

**Nested Lists**

A nested list is a list that contains other lists. A simple example is

```
nested = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5]]
```

You can unpack a nested list (or any list at all)

```
list012, list345 = nested
```

That's what `for count, row in enumerate(game):` is doing.

`enumerate(game)` returns a tuple: a counter and the normal object. We can compare it like this:

```py
my_list = [10,20,30]
for i in my_list:
    print i    # prints 10 20 30
for i in enumerate(my_list):
    print i    # prints (0,10) (1,20) (2,30)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate with maybe a nested list? I think i am starting to grasp it. Could you maybe go more into detail what you mean by destructuring?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate(items)` returns a list of tuples of a number and your item, where the number increases by one for each new item in the list (counting).
In this case enumerate returns the following tuples:

```
{0, [0, 0, 0]}, {1, [0, 0, 0]}, {2, [0, 0, 0]}
```

By using a second variable name in the for loop you are destructuring the tuple into `count` and `row`. Whereas before you were only giving 1 variable name, so the variable was assigned the entire tuple.

Comment: I understand that it gets destructured but into what? `count` and `row` get assigned to what part of the list? Or am I understanding this wrong? Could you elaborate with another example with nested lists like in my code?

Comment: @itsolidude the tuple gets destructured.